# How do I stop Outlook as a GMail client using all my bandwidth?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2013

Last week I tried setting up an Outlook email account to access my GMail (own domain name) inbox via MAPI. It looks like it tried to download my whole inbox, which contains 21,000 mails, at some horrible rate of 20MB/second, and on expensive prepaid 3G, that is a big problem.

I noticed a setting for "Keeping Mail Offline", but the most hopeful options there, on a slider control, are 24 or 0 months. I don't want either. I want to get new mails in Outlook, and maybe the last for the last month or so. It's always just been very convenient for me to not to have to worry about moving mail to archive folders etc. Is that the only solution and nothing I can do on Outlook's side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it in gmail itself and it will download only the new emails

```
Logon to the web based version of Gmail.
Click the Gear icon in the top right corner and choose Mail settings.
Select the “Forwarding and POP/IMAP” tab.
Set the option: Enable POP for mail that arrives from now on.
Press: Save Changes
```

The above will do the trick.